# Rails: Selecting the first 6 posts for a blog and then selecting the 7th and so on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, controller

I am new to rails and I am creating a blog to look simliar to an Esquire website where they have the latest six posts at the top of the page lined up next to each other and then a little down the page they will have a large post by itself which continues the posts array so it would really be the 7th post and then a bit farther down the page you would have the next three posts 8-11 and so on.

I am having a difficult time trying to make the controller an array where I can call the first six items and then the 7th item separately later down the home page.

Posts Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @topsix = @posts.take(6)
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
   @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
   @post.category_id = params[:category_id]
     respond_to do |format|
       if @post.save
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: "post was successfully created." }
           format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
       else
           format.html { render :new }
           format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    @post.category_id = params[:category_id]
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :excerpt, :create_date, :author, :body, :category_id, :image)
    end
end
```

Home Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @topsix = @posts.take(6)
    @first3 = @posts.order('created_at DESC').take(3)
    @sidebar = @posts.take(3)
    @first4 = @posts.take(4)
    @first = @posts.take(1)
  end
end
```

Where I am calling it on the Home page:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <% @topsix.select { |post| post > 6 } %>
    <div class="col-md-2"><%= image_tag post.image.url(:large), class: "img-responsive"%>
      <h6 class="small-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h6>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What you need is: 1) the first 6 post, 2) the 7th post, and 3) the remainder?

Comment: Yes, exactly and to show on the home page

Comment: @Ian, please test my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
@post1to6 = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').first(6) #top 6

@post7 = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').first(7).last #7th

num_post=Post.all.order('created_at DESC').count
@postRemainder = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').last(num_post-7) #Remainder
```

Comment: Good solution, but it can be inaccurate, since the post number can easily change from the first query to the last.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen yours and its better

Comment: It is still throwing a error for "undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x007fb0f71ca7a0>'" It seems that the each method is having a problem only grabbing one item

Comment: @Ian can you please check my answer above?

Comment: Hey @fabriciofreitag yours was correct but everytime you add a post it won't rotate through and if I need to grab the 8th one I can't keep grabbing the last one of the array. I figured it out by the following `class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index</br>
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @onetofive = @posts[0..5]
    @six = @posts[6..6]
    @seven = @posts[7..7]
    @eight = @posts[8..8]
    @ninetoeleven = @posts[9..11]
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

```
all_posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
first_seven_posts = all_posts.take(7)
@first_six_posts = first_seven_posts.take(6)
@seventh_post = first_seven_posts.last
@other_posts = all_posts.where('id NOT IN (?)', first_seven_posts.map(&:id))
```